# Как присвоить объекту значение null в TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Я изучаю Angular по учебному проекту.
У меня стоит 11 версия, в учебнике используется 9.
Определяется переменная:

```
selectedBook: BookModel = null;
```

В коде идет проверка если BookModel = null, то отображается весь список. В примере это все работает.
Но у меня на эту строку

```
selectedBook: BookModel = null;
```

IDE ругается:

```
TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'BookModel'
```

Почему в 11-ой версии ему уже не нравится null и как это теперь корректно записать?
Записать вот так я тоже не могу:

```
selectedBook: BookModel = new BookModel('', '');
```

т.к. это будет уже не null, а на этом этапе у меня еще нет данных для этого объекта

Вот описание BookModel

```
export class BookModel {
  id: string;
  bookName: string;
  constructor(id: string, bookName: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.bookName= bookName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего в настройках tsconfig для компилятора TypeScript указано проверять строгие ссылки на null указанием `--strictNullChecks`. Либо отключите эту опцию, либо явно указывайте null типы.

```
selectedBook: BookModel | null = null;
```

Или так:

```
type Nullable<T> = T | null;
selectedBook: Nullable<BookModel> = null;
```